# How to Load R Work Space with Unknown File Type

Tags: r

I saved my R Work Space yesterday but it is showing as an unknown file type in my folder (literally under "Type" it just says "File"). I would now like to reload the Work Space but got the following error message.

Any suggestions on how to reload the Work Space would be greatly appreciated!

I tried to open the Work Space by right clicking to go to "Open With" but R doesn't show up as one of the programs that I could use to open the file.

```
load("Segmentation.RData")
```

> Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the
>   connection In addition: Warning message: In readChar(con, 5L, useBytes
>   = TRUE) :   cannot open compressed file 'Segmentation.RData', probable reason 'No such file or directory'

Comment: The error message says that there is no file named `Segmentation.RData` in the current folder. You probably need to change your working directory or specify the full path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggests, the file might simply not be found. But the trick here is, that the file cannot be found *where R thinks it is*.

When you start R anew, check that it is running in the correct directory with

```
getwd()
```

Is it running where you think it was? If not, change it! Depending on the interface (console, RGui or RStudio) there are some different dialogs for this, but you can always trust good ol' `setwd`. But mind you if you are using Windows, then you should replace the backslashes (`\`) with forward slashes (`/`)!

Once satisfied that R is running in the correct directory, try `list.files()` and see if the file is found. It might not be called what you were believing it should have been.  You can also try `file.exists("Segmentation.RData")`.

If R is running in the correct directory and R can find the file, and R still does not want to load the .RData file, it might simply be corrupt - or something else entirely.

Comment: This is really helpful! I realized I have simply used the wrong file extension when I loaded. Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome! Remember to mark an answer as useful.